# Using Virtual Hard Disk on Windows7 - The chain of hard disks is broken

Tags: windows, windows-7, vhd

When I tried to attach a .vhd that size is bigger than 5gb, it says `The chain of virtual hard disks is broken. The system cannot locate the parent virtual hard disk for the differencing disk.`

I found a way that seems to be a solution for the problem, but I couldn't understand what should I do?

https://web.archive.org/web/20120420090501/http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/genuinewindows7/thread/1cc44eed-616c-4aa8-b00d-86b8b70bccab/

Comment: Are you using differencing disks, as described at that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this is saying is that you have a differencing VHD file. These are created by storing differences from a parent VHD. To use the file that you have, you need the parent VHD as well, as what you have isn't a disk, it's just a list of changes. As such, you can only mount this file if you also have the parent VHD.

The references you linked to are telling you how to convert from a parent and differencing hard disk into just one actual VHD file, but you need the parent disk file to do that.

If you don't have the parent file then you are completely out of luck, I'm afraid.

Comment: Where did you get the VHD from? The system it was on should have the parent disk on, and you can copy that too.

Comment: I have downloaded it from a website, so I have no chance to work it right without parent vhd. What a pity. I will try to download it from somewhere else. Thank you.